# TCurl/Yab Command to check Cadence server health

Tags: cadence-workflow

I'm looking for a command-line tool to check the cadence server health. I've come across TCurl/Yab, but not able to figure out the exact command to run.

Answer (score 0):

TCurl command to check for cadence server health is:

```
tcurl -p localhost:7933 cadence-frontend --health
```